# Check which dtmf code user types with play_and_get_digits using FREESWITCH

Tags: freeswitch

I want to check if user is typing 1 in DTMF and if does then to log from number. I have tried this but I think condition field do not catch expression ok.

```
<include>
    <extension name="amina" continue="true">
        <condition field="destination_number" expression="^(.*)$">
            <action application="answer"/>
            <action application="play_and_get_digits" data="0 9 1 7000 # /tmp/quothello-therequot-158832.mp3 silence_stream://250 dtmfdig \d+"/>
            <action application="log" data="CRIT digit: ${dtmfdig}"/>
            <action application="info"/>
    </condition>
    <condition field="${dtmfdig}" expression="^1$">
            <action application="log" data="CRIT druga poruka ${dtmfdig}"/>
    </condition>
    </extension>
</include>
```